# GraphQL + Sequelize resolver giving null data

Tags: sequelize.js, graphql-js, apollo-server

Technologies in use:

- NodeJS to run the http server
- ExpressJS framework
- Apollo-server-express for graphQL
- Sequelize to connect to postgres DB
- Postgresql to store data

I am trying to get graphQL working on my node server. Where I am specifically having issues is with the graphql resolver.

I have the following code, which works fine.

```
let User = require('./server/models').User;
let data = User.find({where: {email: "Test@gmail.com"}})
    .then(function (foundUser) {
            console.log(foundUser.dataValues);
            return foundUser.dataValues;
    });

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        user(root, args){
            return data;
        }
    }
};
```

When the client queries the graphql endpoint:

```
query Query{
  user(email:"literallyanything@cangohereATM.com") {
    email
  }
}
```

They always get:

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "email": "Test@gmail.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Which is fine! That is the expected behavior. As is, any parameter can get passed into the query with user(email:"literallyanything@cangohereATM.com") and the results will be the same. Again, that's expected.

When I move the code however, so that the request for data from the database is IN the resolver like so:

```
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        user(root, args){
            User.find({where: {email: "Test@gmail.com"}})
                .then(function (foundUser) {
                    console.log(foundUser.dataValues);
                    return foundUser.dataValues;
                });
        }
    }
};
```

the client will always get this as a response from the graphql endpoint using the same query as before (the console.log outputs the appropriate information however):

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": null
  }
}
```

I suspect I'm failing to understand how apollo-server-express / graphql-tools handles the promise, but I'm not really sure how to move forward from this point. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a GraphQL query return null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56319137/why-does-a-graphql-query-return-null)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a `return` before `User` to ensure your Promises are correctly chained.

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    user(root, args){
      User.find({where: {email: "Test@gmail.com"}})
        .then(function (foundUser) {
          return foundUser.dataValues;
        });
    }
  }
};
```

In your earlier code (when the call to your model resided outside of the resolver), you were returning `data` inside of the resolver. In this case, `data` was not actually your database query result but a Promise that would resolve to that query result. In your updated code, you still have a Promise, but you don't return it inside your resolver function. GraphQL will take the return value and await it if it's a Promise, or otherwise use the value as is -- since you effectively return `undefined`, that's what the resolver uses for the value of `user`.